# Pixel Format Data Structure for ARGB

Tags: image-processing, vnc, vnc-server, argb, rfb-protocol

I'm implementing the RFB protocol (VNC server) in Java.
I'm not able to understand the `PIXEL_FORMAT` provided in the protocol.
The definition of Pixel Format Data Structure is:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| No. of bytes | Type [Value] | Description     |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1            | U8           | bits-per-pixel  |
| 1            | U8           | depth           |
| 1            | U8           | big-endian-flag |
| 1            | U8           | true-color-flag |
| 2            | U16          | red-max         |
| 2            | U16          | green-max       |
| 2            | U16          | blue-max        |
| 1            | U8           | red-shift       |
| 1            | U8           | green-shift     |
| 1            | U8           | blue-shift      |
| 3            |              | padding         |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

The RFB protocol defines the meaning of each flag in detail, but still I'm not able to determine the right values for a raw ARGB image. I'm using the following values:

```
bits-per-pixel  = 32
depth       = 32
big-endian-flag = 1
true-color-flag = 1
red-max         = 255
green-max   = 255   
blue-max    = 255   
red-shift   = 0
green-shift = 0
blue-shift  = 0
padding     = 0
```

While using RealVNC client, I get grayscale image and while using TightVNC client I get four different layers of the image side by side.

Can anyone help me get the right encoding?

Comment: in my case, fb stores data as bgra (ARGB in little endian). So i used `red red-shift   = 16
green-shift = 8
blue-shift  = 0` and i think you should properly get this shift data from `fb_varscreeninfo` structure